# Quais são as diferenças entre os valores "pt" e "pt-BR" do atributo lang?

Tags: html, html5

Não consegui nos testes notar qualquer diferença entre ambos valores. Alguém sabe? Para ajudar: os dois primeiros caracteres do valor definem o Language Code Reference (ISO 639-1) e os dois últimos, após o separador, identificam o Country Code Reference (ISO 3166-1). Mas quando omitimos o Country Code, o que muda efetivamente? Não vejo nada de diferente nos navegadores IE e Chrome e geralmente os desenvolvedores costumam não informar o país.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Vou resumir bem, `pt` indica português, independente do país/região como:

<sup>Fonte: [Which countries and regions speak Portuguese?](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/148/8)</sup>

- Brasil
- Portugal
- São Tomé e Príncipe
- Angola
- Moçambique
- Cabo Verde
- Timor Leste
- Guiné-Bissau
- Guiné Equatorial
- Macau (Macau)<sup>†</sup>

Quando usamos `pt-BR` indicamos português do Brasil, assim como `pt-PT` indica português de Portugal.

O português assim como o inglês tem variações em diferentes países, a indicação do `pt-BR`, `pt-PT`, `pt`, `en`, `en-US`, `en-GB` **não interferem no HTML**, são apenas valores pra informar qual o idioma se encontra, por exemplo alguns navegadores possuem detecção de idioma da página e eles podem repassar pra algum plugin isso, ou um plugin (add-on/extensão) podem usar o atributo diretamente.

Se colocar a URL da página que usa esse atributo no http://translate.google.com ele vai detectar que aquele `<div lang="pt-BR"></div>` usa o português brasileiro (apesar que o google não difere muito ambos).

Outros que geralmente podem usar esse atributo são os buscadores como Google, Bing, Yahoo, Baidu. Os buscadores usam esses atributos pra entregar páginas da preferencia regional e de idioma de uma pessoa que esta buscando.

Agora falando apenas de HTML, o atributo `lang` independente do seu valor, `pt` ou `pt-BR` não muda em nada, a ideia do uso dele é **normatizar** e indicar os tipos de dados pra quem tiver interesse, se não houver esse atributo plugins, google tradutor ou buscadores irão ter dificuldades em detectar o idioma do texto apresentado.

Answer (score 5):

Quando informa só a língua, aquele conteúdo será usado em ferramentas específicas configuradas para aquela língua. Quando informa a língua e o dialeto regional o conteúdo será usado apenas na ferramenta configurada para aquele país. A não ser que não tenha esta configuração, mas tenha da língua, aí ele aproveita o que tem de informação disponível.

O atributo [`lang`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/lang) é mais um que dá semântica ao conteúdo, mas tem nada importante na apresentação.

Esta técnica é pouco utilizada, embora tenha utilidade em vários casos e cada dia é mais necessária em vários cenários. Normalmente a página toda é localizada.

Um dos motivos que pouco muda é que os programadores não se preocupam muito com isto. Eles podem fazer isto conscientemente, priorizando as coisas certas, ou só porque não sabem fazer melhor.

[Tutorial](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-lang-why.en).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).