# Quando devo usar "xml:" na frente de alguns atributos?

Tags: html, html5

Notei que alguns atributos usam `xml:` por exemplo `xml:lang="pt-BR"`? Me parece ser um atributo, mas não é local, nem global. No HTML5, seu uso é necessário?

```
<html xml:lang="pt-BR">

</html>
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Quais são as diferenças entre os valores "pt" e "pt-BR" do atributo lang?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/119113/quais-s%c3%a3o-as-diferen%c3%a7as-entre-os-valores-pt-e-pt-br-do-atributo-lang)

Comment: @DiegoF mas o atributo que está nessa pergunta é diferente da anterior que acredita ser duplicada. Note que ele tem o "xml:" antes de lang. Obrigada :)

Comment: Este xml: é mais antigo que o html5 e não é usado somente com lang, mas com qualquer atributo, editei a pergunta pra torna-la mais proveitosa, talvez mais tarde eu responda se ninguém responder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não precisa do prefixo "xml" a não ser que você queira tratar o seu documento simultaneamente como um decumento XML e HTML. (Não recomendo isso - acho melhor só seguir aas especificações do HTML5)

A [especificação da tag html](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#the-html-element) sugere o uso de um atributo lang, sem prefixo xml:

> Authors are encouraged to specify a lang attribute on the root html element, giving the document's language. This aids speech synthesis tools to determine what pronunciations to use, translation tools to determine what rules to use, and so forth.
>
> ---
>
> Encorajamos os autores a specificarem um atributo lang no elemento html raiz, com a linguagem do documento. Isso ajuda ferramentas de síntese de fala a saberem que pronúncia usar, ferramentas de tradução a saber que regras a usar, etc.

A [especificação do atributo lang](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#attr-lang) vai mais a fundo e diz que você deve usar o atributo sem o prefixo `xml:`. Se você quiser manter compatibilidade com XML / XHTML (algo que normalmente não é necessário) você deve usar tanto o `lang` quanto o `xml:lang`.

> Authors must not use the lang attribute in the XML namespace on HTML elements in HTML documents. To ease migration to and from XHTML, authors may specify an attribute in no namespace with no prefix and with the literal localname "xml:lang" on HTML elements in HTML documents, but such attributes must only be specified if a lang attribute in no namespace is also specified, and both attributes must have the same value when compared in an ASCII case-insensitive manner.
>
> Note: The attribute in no namespace with no prefix and with the literal localname "xml:lang" has no effect on language processing.
>
> ---
>
> Autores não devem usar o atributo lang no namespace XML em elementos HTML em documentos HTML. Para facilitar a migração de e para XHTML, autores podem especificar um atributo sem namespace com o nome literal `xml:lang` mas esses atributos só podem ser usados se um atributo sem o namespace também for specificado, contendo o mesmo valor.
>
> Nota: o atributo com nome `xml:lang` sem especificar o prefixo `xml` não tem efeito no processamento de linguagem.

Comment: Só para deixar bem clara e completa a informação para quem for iniciante: esse prefixo "xml:" no contexto atual chama-se metadata?

Comment: "metadata" é um termo meio vago mas nunca vi sendo usado dessa forma.

Comment: Quanto tempo não o vejo respondendo, sempre com uma ótima resposta +1

Comment: ah, obrigado :>